# Recommended tab is dead

Tags: bug, recommended-tab

1. Open https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended
2. See "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" error.

Unlike invalid values for the `tab` parameter (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=foo), which returns the default "interesting" tab (Without url redirection, notably), this shows the above error with an image such as this:

[image: http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/error-cats/263319349.jpg]

---

**Update: 15:10 UTC** No change on my end. Cache cleared, etc. No change.

[image]

Comment: The tab works for me, actually. I guess something broke for *just you*. Feeling special yet?

Comment: Loaded for me.  Maybe they just wanted you to see the lovely pic.

Comment: It works for me too.

Comment: Still dead here. Why do people keep telling me I'm special?

Comment: It's now dead here... Bear in mind that the whole point of recommeded is that it is **recommended *for you*** so it might be working for others with more simple requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's back working now.

Comment: Nope, it's just broken again, or at least it has for me ;)

Comment: And is now working again. Too much change ;)